# Passing JSON data from Controller to Model

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have the following CodeIgniter application, in which I am trying to read an external JSON file in the controller, and pass it to my model function `getKey()`, and finally, pass data returned from that function to my view.  I keep getting the error message "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)" and I am unsure of what is causing it.  I am new to using CodeIgniter, so any help is appreciated.

My controller:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    var $test_id = 1;
    var $json_key;
    $this->load->model('Test_model');

    $json_key = $this->test_model->getKey($test_id);
    $json_key = json_decode($json_key);
    $data['test_key'] = $json_key;

    $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
}
```

My model:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model{
    var $image_array = array();
    var $test_key = array();
    var $test_name = '';

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getKey($test_id){
        switch($test_id){
            case 1:
                $test_name = "sample1";
                break;
            case 2:
                $test_name = "sample2";
                break;
            case 3:
                $test_name = "sample3";
                break;
        }

        $image_array = file_get_contents('../files/' . $$test_name . '_key.json');
        $test_key = shuffle($image_array);

        return $image_array;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Screen</h1>
    <?php print_r($test_key); ?>
    <?php print_r($json_key); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is wrong. Your code should be in a function. Something like this:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('Test_model');

    $test_id = 1;
    $json_key = $this->test_model->getKey($test_id);
    $json_key = json_decode($json_key);
    $data['test_key'] = $json_key;

    $this->load->view('test_view', $data);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is definitely correct, however, after making the change, I still get the same error, except now it no longer specifies the $this variable, but instead points to the 'var' on line 10.  Any ideas why?

Comment: `var` can't be in a function. You can just leave off `var`. No need for class member variables here. You can just use a local variable. I'll update my answer.